# Is Dynamically allocated array having the same reading and writing speed as normal array for Fortran?

Tags: fortran

I am working with fortran 90, my program depends heavily on accessing different elements of array. So I wonder if reading and writing speed of dynamically allocated array are the same as normal array.

Comment: I do not think it really matters when you are dealing with large arrays.

Comment: The read and write speeds will be the same. However if the compiler knows the size of the array *a priori* it *may* be able to do other optimisations. This is likely to be significant only for small arrays, however like all performance questions the only way you can know for certain is to test it.

Answer (score 4):

I have written a small test program. It accesses an array at random positions and calculates the sum of the elements at these positions. This is done for a normal and a dynamically allocated array. Both arrays contain the same data and are accessed at the same points.

With gfortran and ifort I could not find a significant difference for any size of the arrays.

Here is the code I used. You can adjust the variables arr_size and num_loop to adjust the size of the arrays/ number of runs used for averaging the times. The current parameters (array size = 10 million, 10 averaging runs) have the following runtimes:

Average elapsed time classical array:  0.060910000280 seconds

Average elapsed time dynamically allocated array:  0.060630000010 seconds

Difference in the sum between first and second sum:  0.00000E+00

```
program alloc_test
  implicit none
  ! determines the size of the arrays.
  integer, parameter :: arr_size = 1e7
  ! sets the number of averaging runs
  integer :: num_loop = 10
  integer, dimension(arr_size) :: access
  ! pre allocated array
  real*8, dimension(arr_size) :: arr1
  ! dinamically allocated array.
  real*8, dimension(:), allocatable :: arr2
  integer :: t1, t2, clockrate, i, j
  real*8 :: temp, tot_time, sum1, sum2
  integer :: r_size
  integer, dimension(:), allocatable :: rseed
  !get random seed so the second test uses the same random numbers.
  call random_seed(size = r_size)
  allocate(rseed(r_size))
  call random_seed(get = rseed)
  call system_clock(count_rate = clockrate)
  tot_time = 0
  temp = 0
  do j = 1, num_loop, 1
    call random_number(arr1)
    access = floor(arr1 *arr_size) + 1
    call system_clock(t1)
    do i = 1, arr_size, 1
      temp = temp + arr1(access(i))
    end do
    call system_clock(t2)
    tot_time = tot_time + (t2-t1) /(1.0 * clockrate)
  end do
  sum1 = temp
  write(*,"(a,x,f15.12,x,a)") "Average elapsed time classical array:", tot_time/num_loop, "seconds"

  ! reset random seed:
  call random_seed(put = rseed)
  allocate(arr2(arr_size))
  tot_time = 0
  temp = 0
  do j = 1, num_loop, 1
    call random_number(arr2)
    access = floor(arr2 *arr_size) + 1
    call system_clock(t1)
    do i = 1, arr_size, 1
      temp = temp + arr2(access(i))
    end do
    call system_clock(t2)
    tot_time = tot_time + (t2-t1) /(1.0 * clockrate)
  end do
  write(*,"(a,x,f15.12,x,a)") "Average elapsed time dynamically allocated array:", tot_time/num_loop, "seconds"
  sum2 = temp
  write(*, "(a, e12.5)") "Difference in the sum between first and second sum: ", sum1 - sum2
end program alloc_test
```